# Change background of ImageButton

Tags: android, background, imagebutton

I plan to replace the background (drawable) of the Activity over a `ImageButton`.
How can I proceed?

It is one Day Background and one Night Background. It should always change when I click on the button.
Or how can I check what the background is currently active?
I dont need a fully programmed code.

Comment: Have you looked at State List Drawable?

Comment: Im very new in android programming. No, i have not. Whats that?

Answer (score 2):

Define StateListDrawable in an XML file. Use different images based on state of button. Here's example of XML. I suggest you google for a tutorial for full details

This filename is button_active.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_checked"
    android:state_checked="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />

</selector>
```

Extract from your view xml file which refers to the statelist drawable file

```
   android:background="@drawable/button_active"      

   />
```

Comment: Ok, but i dont want do change the background of the imagebutton. I want change the background of the LinearView Background every time, when i press the imagebutton